# How do I only copy the files changed

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-watch

```
gulp.task('scripts:source', function () {
        gulp.src('./src/admin/assets/scripts/**/*.js').pipe(gulp.dest(adminPath + '/assets/scripts'));
    });
```

and then I have a watch setup on it

```
gulp.watch('./src/admin/assets/scripts/**/*.js', ['scripts:source']);
```

This works and does it copy but it copies all of the files which is an issue since I have 100s of them and the development experience becomes a bit slow. Is there a way to only copy the files which have changed or do I have to live with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at [gulp-newer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-newer)?

> A Gulp plugin for passing through only those source files that are newer than corresponding destination files.

Comment: Haven't looked but looks promising. Thank you Mark :)